# Angularjs customized http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rest api. Some of api controller actions are secured. They use Authentication http header.

```
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: apiEndPoint.concat("/Message/GetMessages"),
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "BEARER ".concat(authorizationService.getAccessToken())
            }
        };

        return $http(options).then(onMessageGetSuccess).catch(onMessageGetFailed);
```

So I am using `headers:{"Authorization":"...}` all of secured rest endpoint.

I want to create a customized http service named `securedHttp` that include:

```
headers: {
           'Authorization': "BEARER ".concat(authorizationService.getAccessToken())
         }
```

How can I customize an http service.

```
angular.service("securedHttp",function(){})
```

Comment: Customized service means do you need to create it as a separate service and invoke from other controllers?

Comment: I think you need [$http interceptor](https://thinkster.io/interceptors)

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP interceptor would be a good approach here. Basically, they're a way to say "do this before all $http requests".

Something like this should work:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function(authorizationService) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       if (needsAuthorization(config)) {
         config.headers.Authorization = "BEARER ".concat(authorizationService.getAccessToken());
       }
       return config;
    }
  };
});
```

See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more info.

Comment: But this apply all http requests. I want to apply Authorization header to (/DeleteProduct/5). But (/GetAll/) will not apply Authorization token.

Comment: You could look at the `config` object and selectively add the Authorization header (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use $httpProvider.interceptors with custom service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

In the example below I keep token in $cookieStore service

Create authInterceptor service (factory)

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);

function authInterceptor($cookieStore){
  return {
    request: function(config){
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if($cookieStore.get('token')){

        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
      }
    },
    responseError: function(response){

      if(response.status === 401){
        // do something when user try to call api without authentication
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and then push that service into $httpProvider.interceptors like this

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

Now if your app found token there will be Authorization key attached to http header

Hope this helps.